# What is axis of the curve?

Tags: trigonometry

So my teacher asked me to fill up a table with the zeros, period, amplitude, etc. of the basic trigonometric graphs. I was able to do all that, but I am stuck when asked for the "Axis of the Curve" for the f(x)=sin(x) and f(x)=cos(x) functions. Could you please provide me with the definition of this term and what it means so I can find it for both of these functions?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you asked your teacher what it means?

Comment: He is probably referring to the equilibrium axis, half way between the max and min - in your cases it is the line $y=0$ but in general for $f(x)=a\sin(kx+d)+c$ it would be $y=c$

Comment: I didn't have the chance to ask, but I googled and got the following definition: "a straight line that bisects at right angles a system of parallel chords and divides the curve into two symmetrical portions". So I would agree that for both sine and cosine, the x-axis would serve as the axis of the curve. I will ask next week, thank you!